# Generalizing a code to work on any size Image

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I have created a function that will tell how much is present in an image, but it only works on square images. How do I generalize this code to tell how much red is present on any size image?

```
Def redness(square):
    All_red = 0
    Others = 0
    For x in range(100):
       For y in range(100):
         Red, green, blue, alpha = square.getpixel((x, y))
         All_red = all_red + red
         Others = others + green + blue
   Return all_red - (others / 2)
```

Comment: Have you tried `width, height = image.size` ?

Comment: I tried and it says image not defined

Comment: You use hard-coded values (the 100s) for x and y, so your code works for only that. If `square` is your image, you need to get its dimensions and use those in the loops. BTW, as is, your code doesn't even compile, with your weird upper case use. You should make sure others can run your code and reproduce your problems on future questions. See also [ask].

Comment: Please edit your question; it is not very clear in terms of coding.